# Is it possible to apply different CSS to images that are above a certain width?

Tags: css

Is it possible to style images that are above 174px differently than all other images without the help of a class or special data attribute on the image?

I’m getting the content for large blog posts with lots of images from an API endpoint. Each image has an array of layout options that can be applied. These come through as classes attached to the image. One of these options is `float-left`. All images with this option need to have slightly different declarations applied, depending on whether or not its natural width is 174px or higher.

Is this possible without manipulating the source data?

Comment: No.. CSS can't **detect** anything so it will not know the width of the image.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example with an example layout options and other details? May be there is some solution that might work for you, but will need a more detailed example to comment on this.

Comment: @Paulie_D — I get what you’re saying. I was thinking more of a media-query-like option that I wasn’t aware of.

Comment: It's possible with JavaScript but not in plain CSS as far as I'm aware.

Comment: _whether or not its natural width is 174px or higher_ - Nope.